# CXF SOAP Fault handling

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I am new to Camel and CXF. I am trying to post process the fault messages that are thrown from my Web Service. But CXF throws them as Fault exception only and hence the camel routing is aborted and the error handler is invoked.

How can I tweak Camel or CXF to get the fault message just as received by the CXF itself?

1. Is there any configuration by which I can attain this?
2. Or Do I need to provide an Interceptor to achieve this?
3. Or Do I need to handle in Error handler?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
from("endpoint")
  .doTry()
    .to("endpoint")
  .doCatch()
    .process(new Processor(
      @Override
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //Get the exception
        SoapFault fault = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, SoapFault.class);

        //Then you can change the body
      }
    ))
  .endDoTry()
.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the sample route in spring DSL. You can try this. This will perfectly work if there is SOAP Fault from the provider.

```
<route id="test-route-id">
        <from uri="direct:from-route"/>
        <doTry>
          <log message="Request Payload : ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="test-route-id"/>

          <to uri="direct:cxf-endpoint"/>

          <log message="Response Payload : ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="test-route-id"/>

          <doCatch>
            <exception>org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault</exception>
            <to uri="direct:fault-handling-route"/>
          </doCatch>
        </doTry>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to react on faults you can do:

onException(Fault.class).handled(true).process(new MyFaltProcessor()).stop();